# JavaFX open new scene with FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scene

So I've been trying to do this for atleast 4 hours now and with no succes.

The case: I need to open a new FXML Window after pressing a button on my Controller class.
I'm using JavaFX for this.
We are working in packages like this.

lobby.gui, login.gui etc...

It doesn't give an error message but the Scene will not start.

This is the LoginFXController where the button is pressed.

```
public class LoginFXController implements Initializable
{
DatabaseMediator mediator;

//INLOGGUI FXML
@FXML TextField tf_inlogusername;
@FXML PasswordField pf_inlogpassword;
@FXML Button btn_inlog;
@FXML Button btn_register;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
     mediator = new DatabaseMediator();
} 

public void loginPersoon(Event event)
{
    String gebruikersnaam = tf_inlogusername.getText();
    String wachtwoord = pf_inlogpassword.getText();
    Persoon p = new Persoon(gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord);
    Boolean check = mediator.controleerPersoonsGegevens(gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord);

    if(check == false)
    {
        showDialog("Error", "Gegevens komen al voor in het Systeem!");
    }
    else
    {      
        showDialog("Succes", "Welkom: " + gebruikersnaam);

        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("lobby.gui/LobbyGUI.fxml"));
            LobbyGUI controller = new LobbyGUI();
            loader.setController(controller);
            loader.setRoot(controller);
            Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             showDialog("Error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }  
}
```

And I'm trying to fire of this new class

```
public class LobbyGUI extends Application
{
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LobbyGUI.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}  

/**
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
 * support. NetBeans ignores main().
 *
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but your code doesn't show where you handle the click event for any button. Without an `EventHandler`, nothing can happen when you click your Button.

Comment: Your `LobbyGUI` class should be removed entirely. `Application` subclasses are for starting your application; your application is already started at this point. Your `loginPersoon` method creates the `Scene` and the `Stage` and displays them. It's not clear why you are calling `setController` and `setRoot` on the `FXMLLoader`; if you have a "regular" FXML file (no dynamic root and `fx:controller` attribute) these won't be necessary.